# How to change Identity User to JWT Token

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity

I have a project written in ASP.NET 4.5.2 MVC. Here Identity is used. Now I will move this project to new ASP.NET Core 6 and here I want to work with custom user and JWT token for users. How can I apply this change so that the passwords of users in the existing database remain active?

Comment: Could you share the database relationship graph?

Comment: maybe this will help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0